# 503 Service Unavailable Error while hosting Django website on CyberPanel

Tags: django, cyber-panel, openlitespeed

I am trying to host my Django website using CyberPanel on OpenLiteSpeed.
I have completed website development. The website is running properly when I run in debug mode (using runserver command). I am trying to deploy the website.

I am using CyberPanel as I wish to deploy my own SMTP server.

I have used the following article to install cyber-panel on my digital ocean server : https://cyberpanel.net/docs/installing-cyberpanel/

I have used the following article to install and configure Django based website on Openlitespeed server https://cyberpanel.net/blog/2019/01/10/how-to-setup-django-application-on-cyberpanel-openlitespeed/

When I try to open website unionelectronics.in I get 503 Service Unavailable (The server is temporarily busy, try again later!) error.

I have updated A record in DNS Management on godaddy to point to my cloud service provider (digital ocean).

Error Log :

```
2021-10-05 14:53:37.241089 [INFO] [817] [config:server:vhosts:vhost:Example] config context /docs/.
2021-10-05 14:53:37.241103 [INFO] [817] [config:server:vhosts:vhost:Example] config context /protected/.
2021-10-05 14:53:37.242757 [INFO] [817] [PlainConf] [virtualHostConfig:] start parsing file /usr/local/lsws/conf/vhosts/unionelectronics.in/vhost.conf
2021-10-05 14:53:37.243519 [INFO] [817] [PlainConf] [virtualHostConfig:] Finished parsing file /usr/local/lsws/conf/vhosts/unionelectronics.in/vhost.conf
2021-10-05 14:53:37.243533 [INFO] [817] [PlainConf] [virtualHostConfig:] context [/] add param [envtype 1]
2021-10-05 14:53:37.251116 [NOTICE] [817] [SSL_CTX: 0x124eb20] OCSP Stapling can't be enabled: [OCSP] /etc/letsencrypt/live/unionelectronics.in/fullchain.pem: X509_STORE_CTX_get1_issuer failed!.
2021-10-05 14:53:37.251224 [INFO] [817] [config:server:vhosts:vhost:unionelectronics.in] config context /.
2021-10-05 14:53:37.257606 [INFO] [817] [PlainConf] [virtualHostTemplate:] start parsing file /usr/local/lsws/conf/templates/ccl.conf
2021-10-05 14:53:37.261988 [INFO] [817] [PlainConf] [virtualHostTemplate:] Finished parsing file /usr/local/lsws/conf/templates/ccl.conf
2021-10-05 14:53:37.262027 [INFO] [817] [PlainConf] [context:/] rewrite [] add rules [rewritefile .htaccess]
2021-10-05 14:53:37.262326 [INFO] [817] [PlainConf] [virtualHostTemplate:] start parsing file /usr/local/lsws/conf/templates/rails.conf
2021-10-05 14:53:37.274452 [INFO] [817] [PlainConf] [virtualHostTemplate:] Finished parsing file /usr/local/lsws/conf/templates/rails.conf
2021-10-05 14:53:37.274503 [INFO] [817] [PlainConf] [context:/] rewrite [] add rules [rewritefile .htaccess]
2021-10-05 14:53:37.274660 [NOTICE] [817] [ZConfManager] No VHosts added, do not send!
2021-10-05 14:53:37.275041 [NOTICE] [817] Instance is ready for service. m_fdCmd 29, m_fdAdmin 6.
2021-10-05 14:53:37.278573 [NOTICE] [817] [AutoRestarter] new child process with pid=848 is forked!
2021-10-05 14:53:37.279309 [NOTICE] [848] [*:80] Worker #1 activates SO_REUSEPORT #1 socket, fd: 22
2021-10-05 14:53:37.279352 [NOTICE] [848] [*:443] Worker #1 activates SO_REUSEPORT #1 socket, fd: 23
2021-10-05 14:53:37.279366 [NOTICE] [848] [UDP *:443] Worker #1 activates SO_REUSEPORT #1 socket, fd: 24
2021-10-05 14:53:37.279406 [INFO] [848] [UDP:0.0.0.0:443] initPacketsIn: allocated 100 packets
2021-10-05 14:53:37.279418 [INFO] [848] [UDP:0.0.0.0:7080] initPacketsIn: allocated 100 packets
2021-10-05 14:53:37.279605 [NOTICE] [848] AIO is not supported on this machine!
2021-10-05 14:53:37.279650 [NOTICE] [848] Successfully change current user to nobody
2021-10-05 14:53:37.279659 [NOTICE] [848] Core dump is enabled.
2021-10-05 14:53:37.279705 [INFO] [848] [union7914.655340]: locked pid file [/tmp/lshttpd/union7914.sock.pid].
2021-10-05 14:53:37.279729 [INFO] [848] [union7914.655340] remove unix socket for detached process: /tmp/lshttpd/union7914.sock
2021-10-05 14:53:37.279781 [NOTICE] [848] [LocalWorker::workerExec] VHost:unionelectronics.in suExec check uid 65534 gid 65534 setuidmode 0.
2021-10-05 14:53:37.279787 [NOTICE] [848] [LocalWorker::workerExec] Config[union7914.655340]: suExec uid 1002 gid 1002 cmd /usr/local/lsws/lsphp80/bin/lsphp, final uid 1002 gid 1002, flags: 0.
2021-10-05 14:53:37.299448 [NOTICE] [848] [union7914.655340] add child process pid: 850
2021-10-05 14:53:37.299497 [INFO] [848] [union7914.655340]: unlocked pid file [/tmp/lshttpd/union7914.sock.pid].
2021-10-05 14:53:37.299538 [INFO] [848] [wsgi:unionelectronics.in:/]: locked pid file [/tmp/lshttpd/unionelectronics.in:_.sock.pid].
2021-10-05 14:53:37.299541 [INFO] [848] [wsgi:unionelectronics.in:/] remove unix socket for detached process: /tmp/lshttpd/unionelectronics.in:_.sock
2021-10-05 14:53:37.306283 [NOTICE] [848] [LocalWorker::workerExec] VHost:unionelectronics.in suExec check uid 65534 gid 65534 setuidmode 0.
2021-10-05 14:53:37.306306 [NOTICE] [848] [LocalWorker::workerExec] Config[wsgi:unionelectronics.in:/]: suExec uid 65534 gid 65534 cmd /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lswsgi -m /home/company_website/companywebsiteproject/companywebsiteproject/wsgi.py, final uid 65534 gid 65534, flags: 0.
2021-10-05 14:53:37.314205 [NOTICE] [848] [wsgi:unionelectronics.in:/] add child process pid: 854
2021-10-05 14:53:37.314305 [INFO] [848] [wsgi:unionelectronics.in:/]: unlocked pid file [/tmp/lshttpd/unionelectronics.in:_.sock.pid].
2021-10-05 14:53:37.314358 [INFO] [848] [lsphp]: locked pid file [/tmp/lshttpd/lsphp.sock.pid].
2021-10-05 14:53:37.314362 [INFO] [848] [lsphp] remove unix socket for detached process: /tmp/lshttpd/lsphp.sock
2021-10-05 14:53:37.314425 [NOTICE] [848] [LocalWorker::workerExec] Config[lsphp]: suExec uid 65534 gid 65534 cmd /usr/local/lsws/lsphp73/bin/lsphp, final uid 65534 gid 65534, flags: 0.
2021-10-05 14:53:37.325014 [NOTICE] [848] [lsphp] add child process pid: 855
2021-10-05 14:53:37.325069 [INFO] [848] [lsphp]: unlocked pid file [/tmp/lshttpd/lsphp.sock.pid].
2021-10-05 14:53:37.325113 [NOTICE] [848] Setup swapping space...
2021-10-05 14:53:37.325224 [NOTICE] [848] LiteSpeed/1.7.14 Open
    module versions:
    modgzip 1.1
    cache 1.62
    modinspector 1.1
    uploadprogress 1.1
    mod_security 1.4
 starts successfully!
```

---

Update  (08-10-2021) :

I deleted  the my old droplet, created a new droplet and reinstalled the entire system.

I have added vHost Conf entry that I added.
I have created a virtual environment company_website and have created companywebsiteproject Project inside the virtual enviroment.

```
docRoot                   $VH_ROOT/public_html
vhDomain                  $VH_NAME
vhAliases                 www.$VH_NAME
adminEmails               kpecengineers@gmail.com
enableGzip                1
enableIpGeo               1

index  {
  useServer               0
  indexFiles              index.php, index.html
}

errorlog $VH_ROOT/logs/$VH_NAME.error_log {
  useServer               0
  logLevel                ERROR
  rollingSize             10M
}

accesslog $VH_ROOT/logs/$VH_NAME.access_log {
  useServer               0
  logFormat               "%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i""
  logHeaders              5
  rollingSize             10M
  keepDays                10  
  compressArchive         1
}

scripthandler  {
  add                     lsapi:union9108 php
}

extprocessor union9108 {
  type                    lsapi
  address                 UDS://tmp/lshttpd/union9108.sock
  maxConns                10
  env                     LSAPI_CHILDREN=10
  initTimeout             600
  retryTimeout            0
  persistConn             1
  pcKeepAliveTimeout      1
  respBuffer              0
  autoStart               1
  path                    /usr/local/lsws/lsphp80/bin/lsphp
  extUser                 union9108
  extGroup                union9108
  memSoftLimit            2047M
  memHardLimit            2047M
  procSoftLimit           400
  procHardLimit           500
}

phpIniOverride  {

}

rewrite  {
  enable                  1
  autoLoadHtaccess        1
}

context / {
  type                    App Server
  location                /home/unionelectronics.in/public_html/KPECproject/
  binPath                 /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lswsgi
  appType                 WSGI
  startupFile             KPECproject/wsgi.py
  env                     PYTHONPATH=/home/unionelectronics.in/public_html/bin/python3:/home/unionelectronics.in/public_html/KPECproject
  env                     LS_PYTHONBIN=/home/unionelectronics.in/public_html/bin/python3
}
```

When I go to http://Server_IP I get 404 error instead of earlier 503 error.
When I go to http://unionelectronics.in/ I get 404 error instead of earlier 503 error.

Earlier I was getting error in error log now I am not getting any error.

I believe the issue is because of

```
index  {
  useServer               0
  indexFiles              index.php, index.html
}
```

How should I reroute to my home page?

If I remove index.html I get 404 error. If I keep index.html I am getting teh default cyberpanel data.

Comment: May I know if the default Django application works? If not, then it means there's something on the server that you need to fix.

Comment: @Eric, when I run my application using the run server command I can access my website over the internet however when I am using the above configuration i.e. cyberpanel with openlitespeed server the I am getting 503 error. When running on cyberpanel I cannot access any part of my django application even the Admin section.

Comment: yes, I saw that. To test default Django is just to verify if your environment setup is correct. maybe this can help, please check https://openlitespeed.org/kb/python-wsgi-applications/#Set_up_Context-2 
e.g. 
"Environment = PYTHONPATH=/var/www/html/lib/python3.8:/var/www/html/demo" 
please substitute the listed python version (python 3.8) with your current one, also the document root path.

Comment: @Eric From Website (management) -> Configurations  -> vHost Conf I have added context I had added. I have updated my original post with this new information.

Comment: Not PYTHONHOME=/home/company_website/ but PYTHONPATH=xxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxx. Please check the env value again. And restart the lswsgi by "killall lswsgi"

Comment: @Eric I deleted the current instance and created new instance. Now instead of 503 error I am getting 404 error. I believe this is because of the index record in my conf file. How do I resolve this? I have attached my vHost Conf file

Comment: Hi, I just set up a default Django site and it works correctly on CyberPanel, I mean both the default page and the admin page load as expected. I think it would be faster if you could join https://litespeedtech.com/slack/ and @eric me there so I can help you directly.

Answer (score 0):

LightSpeed has a web interface which will help you a lot on constructing your context.

If you have access of it would be better. In case you what to know the default path would be you server ip at port 7080. See screenshot provided below

[image]

If you do not know the password you can simply reset it if you have bash access

```
cd /usr/local/lsws/admin/misc 
./admpass.sh
```

example:
[image]

After checking your context I just had few doubts:

"type" provided when I use the Web Interface is "appserver" small cases one word

```
type                    appserver
```

Most example you see on forums is "App Server" which might be pointing on the client side interface when configuring via Web Interface.

Not sure if your config is correct but the current one we are using is
PYTHONPATH points to the "lib" and followed by the :project

```
env PYTHONPATH=/home/domain.name/proj/env/lib/python3.10:/home/domain.name/proj
```

and the LS_PYTHONBIN points to the "bin"

```
env LS_PYTHONBIN=/home/domain.name/proj/env/bin/python3.10
```

> Note: LightSpeed has in built server side caching capability so any changes made are not immediate. So you might have already configured it correctly but does not reflect immediately.